# Reemplazar determinados valores de una variable en un dataframe en R

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame con una variable denominada ingresos (`df$ingresos`).

En esta variable hay datos en euros y miles de euros en formato `string` EJ: "24,4 Miles de euros" y "24785 euros"
Lo que quiero hacer es sacar los de euros, quitar la palabra euros, convertirlos en numérico y dividirlos entre 1000 para pasarlos a miles de euros. He realizado esto y lo he asignado a una nueva variable denominada euros.
Ahora quiero que estos valores sustituyan a los anteriores (solo a los de formato en euros).

He realizado estos pasos

```
library(stringr)

euros <- grep(" euros", df$ingresos, value=TRUE) #Obtengo los valores en euros
euros <- str_extract(euros, "\\d+(,\\d+)?") #Elimino la palabra euros
euros <- str_replace(euros, "[,]", ".") #Sustituyo comas por puntos
euros <- as.numeric(euros) #Convierto en int para poder operar
euros <- euros/1000 #Los convierto en miles de euros
```

Una vez hecho esto me gustaría sustituir los valores de la nueva variable euros, en la variable del dataframe, pero solo en aquellos donde en el string ponía euros a secas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un abordaje similar al usado para extraer los valores que contenían caracteres.
La función `grepl` te permite identificar valores usando `regex`. Si extraes los valores que te interesan en la variable `df$ingresos` puedes indexar el vector que te interesa incluir.

Por ejemplo:

```
df$ingresos[grepl("[a-zA-z]" , df$ingresos)] <- euros
```

Resultado

```
> head(df)
  id ingresos
1  1   0.0244
2  2   24.785
3  3     6122
4  4     2177
5  5    10235
6  6    22162
```

Usé los siguientes datos para el ejemplo y elaboré el vector "euros" con el código que incluiste en la pregunta:

```
set.seed(784)
ingresos = c("24,4 Miles de euros", "24785 euros", sample(30000, size = 10, replace = T))
df = data.frame(id = 1:12, ingresos = ingresos)
```